# how to update ios?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ipad

i have 
xcode=3.2.5

ios=4.2

NOW

i want to update only ios to 4.3

i don't want to update xcode,
how to do so?

Thanks,

Shyam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recent versions of Xcode will work with devices that have newer version of iOS. When you plug it in afterwards it will volunteer to download the symbols; it should "just work" after that. (I say "recent versions" since I'm not sure exactly which version was the first to do that.)

Having said that, I'm not sure that's a good idea for anything other than a point update (i.e., 4.3.1 to 4.3.2). What's your objection to updating Xcode? The download link for Xcode 3 is still present if you'd rather not move to version 4 just yet.

Answer (score 0):

As Jim said, you can't only update the iOS SDK version.

You can, however, install the latest Xcode in another directory and copy over the SDK to your older developer installation.

EDIT: Actually, it depends whether or not you don't want to update *at all*, or just to Xcode 4. The current available version of Xcode 3 includes the latest iOS SDK, 4.3, so you could update to that. Older Xcode versions will probably be phased out eventually, though.

Answer (score -1):

You can't, as far as I know. Apple couples the IDE and the SDK. You can't download one without the other.

Edit: someone may know a way involving copying files from one later XCode installation to an older one, that seems feasible.